# How can I update datasets in Kaggle code script

Tags: python, kaggle

I'm trying to update a dataset in kaggle, but for some reason is importing all columns as just one.

My python code here:

titanic_data = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/titanic-dataset-2/train2.csv')

## Get the column names

column_names = titanic_data

## Print the column names

print(column_names)

(...)

subset = titanic_data[titanic_data['Embarked'] == embarked_location]

Given this I'm getting the following print:
Embarked;Pclass;Sex;Parch;SibSp;Parentes;FareNorm;AgeClass;Survived
S;3;male;0;1;1;7                                                    25;18-26;0
...                                                                        ...
Q;3;male;0;0;0;7                                                    75;27-35;0

[891 rows x 1 columns]

Apparently python code is importing just one column. But in the kaggle dataset columns are showing fine. Is this an encoding problem?
How can I update the csv effectivelly in Kaggle?

Thank you,
PM

I tried already to delete the dataset and creating it again

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the
[sep](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
parameter.

Even though your file is labeled *.csv,
it appears to use `;` semicolon rather than `,` comma
as the field separator.
Share that insight with the .read_csv() function when you call it, and it will behave more to your liking.